# comparing two columns with the similar strings on google sheets and use conditional formatting

Tags: arrays, string, google-sheets, substring, multiple-columns

I have two columns that I am trying to compare.

```
Column 1:
StudentaY-REV
StudentbY-REV
StudentcY-REV 

Column 2:
Studenta
Studentz
Studentk
Studento
```

I want to output a true/false statement, based on whether the substrings in column 2 can be found in column 1 as well. Column 2 is my master sheet and I want to add conditional formatting that colors those cells that could be found in Column 1. Is this possible?
I've tried regexmatch, maybe a better approach would be to somehow compare the lengths of strings since Y-REV concat is standard in Column 1. I wrote a function that concatenated them because I thought it would be easier to do this next step if so.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B1:B)))="", FALSE, TRUE)))
```

[image]